# Can I use/make prediction/regression if my data is not normally distributes? Are non-parametric test for prediction?

Tags: prediction, social-science, nonparametric-regression

My data is not normally distributed, and I`m confused what tests can I use (non-parametric, of course), but is there any way, to analyse prediction if the data is not normally distributed? I read about nonlinear regression, that can be used, but not sure if I understood correct.

Comment: Let's back up a little bit.  What question are you trying to answer and what data do you have?

Comment: I have two predictors/ independent (one personality factor and ACE score)  variables and one dependent variable; collected via questionnaires. The question is, can ACE and personality predict the cyber-victimization?

Comment: Are you interested in prediction, or are you testing a hypothesis?

Comment: Sorry, testing a hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what model you are using for the making prediction if you are using a Linear Model any model which depends on the Euclidian Distance then you must normalize your data if it is skewed. And If You are using tree-based models like Random Forests, Xgboost, ExtraTrees, Catboost etc. then you do not need to normalize your data before feeding it to model and making prediction [Here is a similar question that you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961586/do-i-need-to-normalize-or-scale-data-for-randomforest-r-package#:%7E:text=6%20Answers&text=No%2C%20scaling%20is%20not%20necessary,%2C%20aren%27t%20so%20important.)